# relational drop down in excel

Tags: excel, conditional-statements

I have a drop down of 4 fields in Column A
In column B I have 10 fields which are associated to one of the 4 fields of column A
Similarly I have Column C, where the values are associated to one of the 4 fields of column A

How can I have a relation If I have 3 drop downs where I slect a Column "A" value it gives me related list in the next 2 drop downs.

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called dependent data validation. There are several possible approaches. Debrah Dalgliesh has a very good tutorial at http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html using named ranges and the Indirect() function.

If you need to populate two different drop-downs from one selection, call them Value1 and Value2 based on the Value in the first drop-down and use Indirect(A1&"1") and Indirect(A1&"2") respectively. Like this:

[image]

Comment: +1 for the hat tip to Debra Dalgleish. Agree she has some great tutorials.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but my question is I have 3 lists, when I select list1 value then automatically I need the other 2 drop downs to be auto populated with the related value, [both list2 and List3 should populate depending on List1 selection only]

Comment: I added details to my answer.